# destructure arguments into a function call with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes a variable number of parameters and I have those parameters in an array. The function doesn't take the array as a parameter. What I want to do is destructure the array into the arguments of the function call. I am not sure how long the array is but I know it will be more than 3.

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...etc]
doit(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], ...etc)

function doit( a, b, ...c){
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: “The function doesn't take the array as a parameter.” Is that by design, or would you be willing to accept an array parameter? Do the parameter variables need distinct names (a, b, c etc) or would an array do? What version JavaScript do you have available?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you should just *spread* `array` into the call of `doit`:

```
doit(...array);
```

Note that this is called *spread* (or "spread syntax"), which is not destructuring. Destructuring involves either creating a new variable, or assigning to an existing variable.

The older method would be to use `apply`:

```
doit.apply(undefined, array);
```

Comment: @ CapitalJusticeWarrior - With your existing declaration (`function doit(a, b, ...c)`), which is valid even if you may have just meant it as shorthand, if you do the above you'd get the first array element as `a`, the second as `b`, and the rest of them in as an array in `c` (that declaration for `c` is called a *rest parameter*).

Comment: Thanks! I was only thinking of using the spread within array brackets.

Comment: @CapitalJusticeWarrior Note that compatibility, while high, is not uniform, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) and for [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) too. (Probably not an issue if spread works in your process already, but you might consider Babel just to be safe, if you aren't already, if you want to support ancient browsers)

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to use the special variable `arguments` inside any javascript function. You will gain access to all arguments, regardless of their count.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var arr2 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

doit(arr1);                               // one argument: [a,b,c,d,e,f]
doit(arr2);                               // one argument: [A,B,C]
doit(arr1[0], arr2[1], 'anything', -3.1); // four arguments: a, B, 'anything', -3.1

function doit(){
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log("argument " + i + " is : " + arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The question asks how to destructure, not how to access by index operator which will not work for an array of unknown length. It is also not asking how to handle an unknown number of arguments in a function.